# Matlab - second derivative of data

Tags: matlab, derivative

Let's say we have

```
[x]=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
[y]=[0.25 0.30 0.40 0.55]
y1=diff(y)./diff(x)
y2=diff(y1)./diff(x)
```

And the result I get is

> Matrix dimensions must agree

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Check [whether](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) you need to transpose one of the matrices to operate them as intended.

Comment: In the last line, `diff(y1)` is a vector of length 2 and `diff(x)` is a vector of length 3, hence it's giving you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redirect you towards [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) documentation. When you use the diff function, it will actually return you a vector with m-1 (m being its length), since what it does is output this:

```
diff(y1) = [y1(2)-y1(1) y1(3)-y1(2) ... y1(m)-y(m-1)]
```

As you can see, you will loose one value, and thus explaining your error. When you do your last line, it cannot divide diff(y1) by diff(x) since diff(y1) is equal to a vector of length 2 and diff(x) is equal to a vector of length 3.

Depending on what you want to do, you can change the code to the following :

```
[x]=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
[y]=[0.25 0.30 0.40 0.55]
y1=diff(y)./diff(x)
y2=diff(y1)./diff(x(1:end-1))
```

If you want to approximate the derivate of y, I really suggest you to take a look at the example in the page I linked. The matlab documentation always gives examples on how to use their functions, so [go take a look](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). According to the documentation, if you want to calculate the partial derivate of the vector y, you need the step of your x vector.

```
x=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
y=[0.25 0.30 0.40 0.55]
x_step = 0.1
y1=diff(y)./x_step
y2=diff(y1)./x_step
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4] ;
y=[0.25 0.30 0.40 0.55] ;

dy = gradient(y)./gradient(x) ;
d2y = gradient(dy)./gradient(x) ;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem some explanation of why/how it does so would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: Note that the [`gradient`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html#bvifdfu-5) calculates its boundary gradients differently than the inner points. This may result in unwanted end effects.